# return type not being accepted?

Tags: c++

this is my code

```
char* Item::getsku()const{
    return _sku*;
}
```

header file

```
char _sku[MAX_SKU_LEN + 1 ];
char* getsku()const;
```

i get the error

```
Item.cpp: In member function ‘char* sict::Item::getsku() const’:
Item.cpp:54:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
```

its say that's it's expected a primary expression before the semi-colon but it's only meant to be a getter function. everytime i change it, i get unable to change const char* to char

Comment: What is `_sku`? are you wanting to do `return &_sku;`?

Comment: What is `_sku*` supposed to be ?

Comment: so you want to `return _sku;`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
char _sku[];
```

Then you just need

```
return _sku;
```

..or..

```
return &_sku[0];
```

But, I'd avoid variable names with leading underscores. There are complex rules regarding their use. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

**Added**: You've also got a problem with `const` correctness. You're trying to return a non-const pointer to an internal character array of a `const` object (because your method is const). If you don't want callers to be able to modify the array contents, then you should have a return type of `const char *`

Or, if you *do* want callers to be able to modify the characters, then your `getsku` method should not be `const`.

Comment: This isn't actually true - it's reserved for double leading underscores, and single underscores followed by a capital letter (see lib.global.names in the standard).

Comment: @ajshort It's more complex than either of us thought :)

Comment: now it's just saying error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return a pointer to char, so i could imagine that you variable _sku is a char *.

the `*` has two purposes.

The first use to `*` is at variable declaration to precise that the variable that you are declaring is going to be a pointer on a type, or object.

```
 char * str;
 int  * i;
 Object * object;
```

The second one, in front of a variable which is a pointer on a type, type doesn't matter, the `*` is used to dereference variable and get access to its value.

```
int * a;

*a = 7;
```

i used `*` to dereference 'a' and set value (7) to our int which is pointed by a.

`*` needs a right operand that is why you get this error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
```

If _sku is of type `char *` you just have to write:

```
return _sku;
```

However if _sku is a char and that you want to return its adress (a pointer on it) you should write:

```
return &_sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* Item::getsku()const{
    return _sku;
}
```

(I removed the '*' after `_sku`, assuming it was a typo)

The problem is that `getsku` is a **const** member function, so all members of class `Item` are treated as `const` while inside it. Since `_sku` is the name of an array, it decays into a pointer to the first element of the array, so that's okay. But the **type** of that pointer is `const char*`, because this is a const member function.

Without knowing more about the design, it's not really possible to give an answer, but often this requires two member functions:

```
const char* Item::getsku() const {
    return _sku;
}
```

and

```
char* Item::getsku() {
    return _sku;
}
```